# SpringDataJpa: Multiple ContainingIgnoreCase

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have something like below. basically I want to get all the books contains certain keywords in their title or description. Spring keep giving me error on this method. Single select of either Title or Descr works, but I am just not able to put them together. What am I missing?

works:

```
findBookByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(String keyWord)

findBookByDescrContainingIgnoreCase(String keyWord)
```

doesn't work:
 `findBookByTitleContainingIgnoreCaseOrDescrContainingIgnoreCase(String keyWord)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
findByTitleContainingIgnoreCaseOrDescrContainingIgnoreCase(String title, String descr);
```

You can then call this method as `bookRepository.findByTitleContainingIgnoreCaseOrDescrContainingIgnoreCase(keyword, keyword)`

An easy way to remember how to form queries with Spring Data JPA is to keep in mind that method names eventually become JDBC `PreparedStatement`s.  Each keyword (class attribute) in the method name becomes a parameter in the `PreparedStatement`.  Consequently, each of the parameters must be bound to a value when the `PreparedStatement` is executed.  Therefore, the method must have equal number of arguments for the `PreparedStatement` to execute correctly.

When you apply this thinking to your problem, you will see that your method name has two keywords - `Title` and `Descr` but only one parameter.  So, the second parameter in the `PreparedStatement` remains unbound when the `PreparedStatement` is executed; hence the error.  Supplying both parameters solves the problem.

Sample code with working test cases on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/33792288).

Answer (score 0):

`findBookByTitleContainingIgnoreCaseOrDescrContainingIgnoreCase(String keyWord, String keyWord2);` fixed my problem.